# When do Dijkstra and the Bellman-Ford algorithm both fail to find a shortest path?

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path

I know Dijkstra fails when there are negative edge weights, but when do both algorithms fail?

Comment: When there is no path to be found?

Comment: Dijkstra doesn't always fail when there are negative edge weights, it just doesn't always succeed.

Answer (score 4):

If there are negative cycles (reachable from the source), Bellman-Ford can be considered to fail. The main problem with a negative cycle is that you can just keep traversing it, reducing the cost of the path, thus there exists no finite shortest path to some vertices (so it's arguable whether Bellman-Ford actually failed or not - it can detect these cycles).

Dijkstra's algorithm will have a similar problem with negative cycles (not to mention the more general problem of dealing with negative edge weights).

Another scenario can be unreachable vertices, but again you can just detect that they're unreachable.

Comment: Hah we thought the same but I beat you with 10 secs ;) Btw both algorithms will successfully report if the destination is not reachable if correctly implemented so this should not be an error

Comment: @Bernhard Barker, what do you mean when you say '..reachable from the source'? I had assumed that to be _any_ negative cycle in the graph, but when you say the above, does that mean anything different?

Answer (score 1):

Both algorithms will not find a shortest path if the graph contains a negative cycle and this cycle is reachable from the source node and the destination node is reachable from the cycle. In this case there is no shortest path - you may perform infinitely many iteration over the cycle always reducing the path length.

Answer (score 0):

Since a shortest path doesn't exist if there's a negative cycle, and Bellman-Ford can detect negative cycles, you can argue that it never fails. (similarly because you can detect when there is no path between two vertices)